# How to create a clean theme branch in git which only has one commit (and no pulls from upstream)

Tags: git, github

### Forking prezto

I forked sorin-ionescu/prezto (`upstream`) from github to my github account (nasenatmer/prezto) (`origin`), cloned it locally and started configuring it, adding files, while constantly committing and pushing changes back to my github repo.

### Configuring my local repo

Among other things, I modified a prompt theme which I now want to give back to the project and thus I'd like to create a  pull request`. Learning from the github "using pull requests" and a tutorial on gun.io, I tried to create theme branches, commit my changes so I can forward them as pull requests on github. However, in the meantime, there were updates in upstream.

So I had the following commit history:
`original checkout - - many "private commits" - - -  pull upstream changes`

### Creating a theme repo

So in order to create a theme repo, I created a branch at my earliest clone from upstream which I called `pristine` and which I won't customise myself. I then pulled from `upstream` to bring `pristine` up-to-date.

From that point I branched off `prompt_jakob_setup` (that's the name of the prompt file) and committed the file to it.

### The problem of too many commits

Now, if I go to `github` to start the pull request from my theme branch, I always see [two commits](http://git.io/aGPCkg) from today: the pulling in `upstream` and my prompt commit.

I don't think any maintainer would accept such an unprofessional pull request?

### The Question

What is the right way to create a clean themed branch which only has the one commit you want to push upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the upstream merges you want to `git rebase upstream master`.

You can also do `git pull --rebase upstream master`.  Which will do a `fetch` before `rebase` so that you are sure that you are up to date.

This will move your commits to after any commits that happened on the upstream repo.  And not show the commit message that you are concerned about.  If you want to change the current repo you will want to `git reset --hard` to your commit (undoing the merge from upstream) and then proceed with the `git rebase`.  If you have pushed these changes to your own repo on GitHub you may have to do a `git push --force` so that you overwrite the history.  (I generally recommend against doing this but since it is your repo, it should be ok.)